# Python 2.6.6 doesn't work properly

Tags: python

I am working with RedHat Linux 5.6 (in case that matters).

My team is working with python 2.6.6. I installed it from source (configure, make, make install) from the official Python site. It seems to not work properly:

1. When I type `python` in the terminal to enter the Python CLI, for some reason I can't delete what I type (backspace prints character marks to screen)
2. Modules like psutils are missing (this should be a standard part of Python, no?)

Python 2.4, which was previously installed, works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: backspace "didn't works" only after you enter python cli ?

Comment: Well, [`psutil`](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) is not a built-in module

Comment: My guess for the CLI issues is that you're missing the headers for the GNU Readline library. Check if your OS has a `libreadline6-dev` package, or something similar (I don't know Redhat's package naming conventions and it seems I need to be subscribed to something or other in order to even browse their package lists). Python's `configure` script will detect automatically if readline is available and use it, but it may not give you a very obvious notice if it doesn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

psutil is not a standard module. You will have to:

```
easy_install psutil
```

or

```
pip install psutil
```

in the terminal.

About the symbol when pressing backspace. '^?' symbol will appear on pressing backspace, if your insert option is on. Switch off insert (by pressing insert button on the keyboard) then try backspace.

Comment: Thanks. The '^H' appears. insert button doesn't help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Install `readline-devel` from yum and then recompile Python. Command line editing magics require this library.